# Import a CSV to a DB with multiple tables, OneToMany Relationship - Looking for a Good Example

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-import-export

I'm using the django-import-export package to move data in and out of my app.

I have a flat csv dataset that I need to import. Each row of the csv has fields that need to be parsed and imported to a secondary db table with a one-to-many relationship.

I already read through the django-import-export docs and the "import data workflow" section, but I have been unable to find a good example that shows importing OnetoMany with multiple tables - it seems like everyone's standard example involves importing data into a single db table - not helpful in my scenario.

Here is an example of my data model.

```
#models.py

class SlateDoc(models.Model):

    #primary Model - fields not listed here.


class ActTimecodes(models.Model):

    #Secondary model - every slatedoc can have multiple instances of ActTimecodes

    slatedoc = models.ForeignKey(
              SlateDoc, 
              on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
             related_name="acts"
            )
    act_number = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Act", default=1)
    tc_in = models.CharField(max_length=11, default="00:00:00:00")
    tc_out = models.CharField(max_length=11, default="00:00:00:00")
    dur = models.CharField(max_length=11, default="00:00:00:00")

    objects = ActTimecodesQuerySet.as_manager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["act_number", "tc_in", "tc_out"]
```

And here is an example of the CSV data to import:

| id | filename | int_house_num | series_title | episode_title | producer | act_01_in | act_01_out | act_02_in | act_02_out | act_03_in | act_03_out | act_04_in | act_04_out | act_05_in | act_05_out | act_06_in | act_06_out | act_01_dur | act_02_dur | act_03_dur | act_04_dur | act_05_dur | act_06_dur |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 061846_Filename_2398p_EM.mov | 061846 | Cool Series | The Quiet Place | Mr.Pink | 01:00:00:00 | 01:10:04:09 | 01:10:06:09 | 01:16:59:22 | 01:17:01:22 | 01:25:31:11 | 01:25:33:11 | 01:31:37:03 | 01:31:39:03 | 01:39:04:14 | 01:39:06:14 | 01:44:06:08 | 00:10:04:09 | 00:06:53:13 | 00:08:29:13 | 00:06:03:16 | 00:07:25:11 | 00:04:59:18 |

Each column with the "act_X_in", "act_X_out", "act_X_dur" needs to be translated to
a row in the ActTimecodes model.

So for this example, there would be 6 rows created in the ActTimecodes model for a single SlateDoc object.

I'm assuming that I need to write a custom import_data() method?
But not sure where to start, or if there are any other methods that need customization.

If anyone could point me to an example that illustrates the best approach for this type of import, I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

django-import-export has a number of methods which you can extend to customize the import.  If you define a resource with a primary model, then the fields which correspond to that model will be imported as defined.

Where you have fields which are in a secondary model, you can override methods to extract, create and save those objects as required.

This gets more complicated if you need to check whether existing secondary rows already exist (and update them if so), but the basic principle would be:

```py
class SlateDocResource(resources.ModelResource):

    def after_import_row(self, row, row_result, row_number=None, **kwargs):
        # At this point, the primary object is persisted.
        # row data is stored in the 'row' dict.
        # you can dynamically iterate over the row to pull out values 
        # to create and save AclTimecodes instances
        pass


    class Meta:
        model = SlateDoc
        # you can define fields here as required - see docs
        fields = ('id', 'filename')
```

Comment: thanks, I think you answer helps me get closer to what I need.

Comment: The problem I have now is that the ActTimcodes model uses a model method from the SlateDoc model in order to determine  the field value for "dur", and that is causing an import error. `python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 215, in __get__
raise self.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist(
slatedoc.models.ActTimecodes.slatedoc.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: ActTimecodes has no slatedoc..`   Not sure how I need to handle this new error.

Comment: I think the issue is that I'm trying to create the ActTimecode instance with `ActTimecodes.objects.create()` so each actbreak instance has no connection to the the parent slatedoc object. but I'm not sure what I need to do to fix this.